# Edit existing building in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've created and exported a building using the building editor*. Is it possible to open that building up in the editor to change it?

*Awesome tool by the way. Thanks guys!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/11978/edit-existing-building-in-gazebo?/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2015-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, currently it is not possible to edit it back with the building editor ([issue #1634](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1634/edit-existing-building)).

You can edit some aspects of it in the model editor, but all the information about what is a wall, a door and so on is lost.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2015-11-04**:
Shame :(   Thanks for the answer though.